# Window access on secure DOM (LockerService)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I am trying to change my application to match the LockerService requirements and one of the issues I've ran into are using listeners that need access to the window object. I need to resize my components according to the size of the window, and this requires that I get window information like this.

```
var height = $(window).height();
```

This used to give the window height prior to LockerService, but now it returns 0, and the actual window object returned doesn't have a visible height field.

TestApp.app

```
<aura:application >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', $Resource.jquery, $Resource.customjs)}"  />
</aura:application>
```

Customjs

```
window.setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(function() {
        resizeContent();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            resizeContent();
        });
        function resizeContent() {
            var height = $(window).height()-244;
            $('#ConversationBox').height(height); 
        }
    }), 1
);
```

What is the correct way to fetch the window height now that things are quarantined with the whole secure DOM aspect and your JS only being to reach DOM objects that it created?

Comment: Hi @JasonLee, Did you get any workaround to fetch the window height/width which works even when LS is active?

Comment: @SE_User : Nope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've identified the issue within LockerService and it's in our queue to fix.

Please open a case with support and tell them to link to our internal work item W-3198557.

Comment: Any ETA on the fix for this? support closed my case so I don't know the progress.

Comment: It's one of the items being worked on within the team, no exact ETA yet.

Comment: @Trevor Any updates on the fixes? we are also facing similar issues.

Comment: @Trevor - Is there a Known Issue available for this, which we can follow to get the update automatically?

Comment: Hi @Trevor Is there any update regarding this issue?

Comment: Hi @TrevorBliss Can you please update on this?

Comment: Hi @JFParadis / Trevor Could you please provide an update regarding this issue?

Comment: Hi @TrevorBliss Could you please provide an update on this?

Comment: @SE_User Actively working on a solution now.

Comment: @SE_User This is fixed in the main Aura codebase, but is not currently planned to be released until Spring '17.

Comment: Hi @TrevorBliss Is the scroll issue also being planned to be released in Spring '17? [Unable to add custom scroll due to “component/namespace encapsulation” when Locker Service is active](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151463/unable-to-add-custom-scroll-due-to-component-namespace-encapsulation-when-lock?noredirect=1#comment222097_151463)

Comment: @SE_User no update on the scrolling issue you linked to you linked to yet. Apologies. I asked someone to take a look at the other <lightning:textarea> scrolling issue you posted though, hopefully they respond. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141272/lightningtextarea-scroll-not-working-when-the-content-exceeds-the-container-h

Comment: Thanks a lot @TrevorBliss for the update. Also, it would be very grateful if you could ask someone to look into the main, basic scroll functionality in Salesforce1 app in iOS and Android devices. Scroll is a basic as well as very IMPORTANT functionality. The previous "workaround" in the Salesforce Issues page was not to include content which exceed the viewable area which is not even a workaround! Once again, thank you for looking into this.

Comment: @TrevorBliss There's still no update regarding the scroll issue in <lightning:textarea>! Still, the default scroll doesn't work. Also, there's yet another issue where in, even using `ui:scrollerWrapper` is not smooth. I've created an unmanaged package to replicate the issue. Here's the link to question:- [Scroll issue in Salesforce1 | Lightning ui:scrollerWrapper issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173467/scroll-issue-in-salesforce1-lightning-uiscrollerwrapper-issue)

Answer (score 3):

Just a thought on approaching this from a different angle: Remember that Locker will bar you from seeing DOM elements outside your Lightning namespace, but your components can still see one another.

There is a way to set dimensions relative to the height or width of the viewport in pure CSS using the `vh` and `vw` units. For example if your top-level component has this CSS:

```
.THIS {
    height: 90vh;
}
```

Then it means the element will size up to 90% of the available viewport. I can't be confident right now of expected results but at least in theory you can query that top-level component's height (whether through the DOM or events) and use it to trigger changes in other components' sizes.

Answer (score 1):

`document.height` is obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/height

jquery is doing some magic under the hood to preserve the API, but you could replace that line with `var height = document.clientHeight`, and that should work just fine inside the LockerService.

note: we will get someone to investigate what's going on with jquery internals anyways.

Comment: Hmm, document.documentElement.clientHeight seems to return the correct height when run manually inside my browser's console, but not from within the application.. It returns 0 just like $(window).height() .