# Highcharts tooltip getting overlapped by graph when locker service is activated

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, highcharts

I'm facing an issue where Highcharts tooltip is being overlapped by the graph itself.
Please find the following image which depicts the same:

**When LS is active:**

[image: Highcharts tooltip getting overlapped by graph]

**When LS is deactivated**

[image: Highcharts works fine when LS is not active]

(The scale of the two graphs are different because I'm setting dynamic height for the chart using [$(window).height() which hasn't been fixed by Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127300/window-access-on-secure-dom-lockerservice) yet when LS is active.)

Code:

**Helper:**

```
drawChart : function(component, helper) {
        if(component.isValid() && component.get("v.isResourcesLoaded") 
           && component.get("v.isDataChanged")) {

           var stackedColumnChartObj = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: component.find("stackedColumnChart").getElement()
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },                        
                xAxis: {
                    categories: labelList,
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    labels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '`{value}'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: [{
                    enabled: true,
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }                                         
                }],
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        animation: false,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }                                    
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                     useHTML: true,
                     borderWidth: 0,
                     borderRadius: 0,
                     backgroundColor:"rgba(255,255,255,0)",
                     shadow: false,
                     formatter: function(){
                        var s = this.series.name + ': '+ '<br/>Total: '  
                                +this.stackTotal;       
                        return ("<div class='tooltip'>" + s + "</div>");
                     },
                    enabled: !component.get("v.isDrillDown")
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: columnDataList                  
          });
}
```

**Renderer:**

```
({
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
    },
    rerender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superRerender();   
        helper.drawChart(component, helper);        
    }
})
```

**CSS:-**

```
.THIS .highcharts-tooltip span .tooltip{    
    z-index:999999999 !important;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: white;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

This issue is not present when locker service is deactivated. But I want this to work perfectly when LS is deactivated. It would be very helpful if anyone can provide any insights regarding this.

**Edit:**
As per Pawel's suggestion I rendered the tooltip as HTML (I've edited the Highcharts initialization code above). The tooltip renders in Chrome device simulator. But in iPad and iPhone, it throws the following errors on clicking the graph:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.call')
>
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'charts[H.hoverChartIndex].mouseIsDown')

Comment: May be a stupid question but what if you used css to make the z-index 10000 or something large to bring it to the front?? Little hacky...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Eric. But unfortunately this doesn't work as Highcharts renders the tooltip and graphs as svg elements. So I think there's reordering (which is using JS) required to bring it to the front. Also, this issue is not present when Locker Service is deactivated. I'm facing this issue when Locker Service is activated.

Comment: I don't know what is the reason, but using Highcharts you can force tooltip to be rendered as HTML element, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML) and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nr4346nm/). Note: I needed to disable default border/backgroud and use CSS to add these styles, to make sure we have HTML, not SVG.

Comment: SE_User have you tried what Pawel Fus suggested, looks like it would work

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion @PawełFus. Hi Pawel and Praveen, I did the same and was able to render the tooltip as HTML too and it works fine in Chrome device simulator (when Locker Service is activated). But it does not work in iPad as well as in iPhone. It throws the following errors on click 1. (TypeError: null is npot an object (evaluating 'e.call')). 2. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'charts[H.hoverChartIndex].mouseIsDown')

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Highcharts. Do you have the same issue with my demo on iPhone/iPad ? Could you tell me a file and a line number here: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.call')` ?

Comment: Hi @PawełFus . Your demo works fine when taken in the browser (jsfiddle). My issue is when I'm implementing your suggested solution inside Salesforce1 app. Since I'm not getting an error in browser device simulator, I'm unable to provide you the exact line number of the error too.

Comment: Can you check which version of Highcharts Salesforce1 app is using? Current version of Highcharts is 4.2.6.

Comment: Hi @PawełFus, We're using Highcharts version 5 (Yes, the development edition) (https://code.highcharts.com/5/js/highcharts.src.js).

Comment: Ah, dev version. Well, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nr4346nm/4/ - copy & paste code between `start` and `end` into your project, before creating a chart. Most probably version 5 (dev-preview) has not [this bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/c17dc193ee6f786c8cb1b265c40babdb09f7a077) fixed yet.

Comment: @SE_User - were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi @PawełFus Thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately this did not fix the problem (I entered your code which you told to just before initialising).
And now the error is "[NoErrorObjectAvailable] NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist." But it's throwing this error inside Salesforce1 app.  (It's not throwing this error when taken in Chrome mobile simulator, also the tooltip is still not fine in simulator too.. It's still the same as in screenshot which I posted)

Comment: Hmm.. the best I think is to try out 4.2.7 version to see if this is fixed in the current, stable version. Could you do that? Just for testing?

Comment: Hi @PawełFus Since version 4.2.7 isn't locker service compatible it didnt work. Also Highcharts has released stable version 5 which is compatible in strict mode I believe.

Comment: And you have the same issue with 5.0.0 ? As I can see, the error should vanish: `if (!defined(H.hoverChartIndex) || !charts[H.hoverChartIndex] || !charts[H.hoverChartIndex].mouseIsDown) { ... }`. Array `charts` can have `undefined` or `chart` object so it should not happen anymore.

Comment: Hi @PawełFus This issue has been fixed in the latest stable version of the Highcharts as well as in Salesforce's Winter '17 12.1 patch. Also, the old issue of error 16 is still coming up in the latest stable version. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147917/mutiple-highchartsv5-components-not-rendering-when-locker-service-is-active-err

Comment: Great to hear that! Regarding #16 issue - component everytime loads Highcharts. Highcharts should be loaded just once.

Comment: Hi @PawełFus Just a quick update, Highcharts Error #16 is present in Microsoft Edge browser in windows Desktop.