# lightning:textarea | Scroll not working when the content exceeds the container height in Salesforce1 | Winter '17

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-design-system, scrolling, winter17

I'm facing an issue where scroll is not working in one of the newly released Lightning Base Component in the Winter '17 namely **lightning:textarea**.

The cursor even moves out of the textarea when tried to scroll down or upwards as shown in the screenshots posted below in the Salesforce1 app.

**CODE:** (to reproduce the issue in Winter '17 pre release org)

**Component:-**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <lightning:textarea name="myTextArea" value="Initial value" 
    label="What are you thinking about?" maxlength="300" class="lightningTextarea"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**CSS:-**

```
.THIS .lightningTextarea textarea{
    height:100px;
}
```

**Screenshot 1 (iPad)**

[image]

**Screenshot 2 (iPad)**
[image]

In case of Android devices, you'll be able to scroll by clicking on to the cursor and then trying to scroll up or down.

Comment: ui:scrollerWrapper also had similar issues but with the latest update it seems to be working. Can you check this lightning:textarea also after latest update. seems like this needs a fix from SF team.

Comment: @PintuFrancis No, there's no change, still the scroll functionality is not working in lightning:textarea.

Comment: Summer '17 is round the corner and still the same issue persists! @DougChasman @TrevorBliss @JFParadis Can you guys please take a look at this? Also regarding the `ui:scrollerWrapper` [issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173467/scroll-issue-in-salesforce1-lightning-uiscrollerwrapper-issue)?