# Salesforce1 Lightning component won't scroll on iphone

Tags: salesforce1-app, scrolling

I have built a lightning component which loads and scrolls correctly in SF1 on an iPhone 5.  It calls other component pages, but those pages won't scroll at all on an iPhone even though they scroll correctly in the simulator.

I have tried assigning the class "slds-scrollable_y" to the containing div, but that doesn't help.

Not that this should matter, but I am calling the supporting component pages like this:

```
navigateToArticle : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:SalesCenterKnowledgeDetail",
        componentAttributes: {
            GroupId : 123
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched farther and found a solution in this article [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173467/scroll-issue-in-salesforce1-lightning-uiscrollerwrapper-issue?rq=1)

It doesn't solve the issue entirely though because there seems to be limited child page functionality, such as losing the ability to pull down for refresh.  If anyone can identify the cause, that may help to discover a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, work around is create a Lightning component tab, then
navigate to the tab URL, NOT directly navigate to component by using 
$A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");